# SQL: how do I make this COUNT(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <true> END) AS <name>

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this piece of SQL code that I want to make dynamic:

```
SELECT
    state as 'hc-a2',
    COUNT(*) AS 'total',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN nature = 'nature_1' THEN nature END) AS 'nature_1',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN nature = 'nature_2' THEN nature END) AS 'nature_2',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN nature = 'nature_3' THEN nature END) AS 'nature_3'
FROM [MY_DATA_BASE].[DBO].[MY_TABLE]
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY state
```

Because I can't enumerate all the natures in the database I can't keep running a query like this.

I need to make this `CASE statement` dynamic, this part specifically:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN nature = 'nature_1' THEN nature END) AS 'nature_1',
COUNT(CASE WHEN nature = 'nature_2' THEN nature END) AS 'nature_2',
COUNT(CASE WHEN nature = 'nature_3' THEN nature END) AS 'nature_3'
```

I'm simply stuck because I don't know if it's possible.

Hope someone can enlighten my path on this.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for this.  Have you done any research on your own yet?

Comment: Google:  "sql server dynamic pivot"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I did! That's why I went from a 189 lines query to this with the same result. Now I just need a little help, right?!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you so much!!!